# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el formulario si se cumple una condición en PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Como puedo lograr que si el usuario que ha ingresado en su cuenta tiene valores en la base de datos haga que se muestre un formulario distinto.

Este serie el primer formulario:

```html
<form method="POST" class="mt-4 mb-4 col-lg-6">
                <input class=" mb-3 form-control" type="disabled" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre?>" >
                <input class="mb-3 form-control" type="text" name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" value="<?php echo $apellidos?>">
                <input class="mb-3 form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" value="<?php echo $email?>">
                <input class="mb-3 form-control" type="phone" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" value="<?php echo $telefono?>">
                <input name="id" type="text" value="<?php      echo $show['id']; ?>">
                <div class="col mt-3 text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Cambiar</button>
                </div>
                <!-- <p class="mt-5"><?php print_r($resultado) ?></p> -->
                
            </form>
            
             <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Y este sería el formulario que quiero mostrar si el usuario tiene datos en la base de datos.

```html
<form method="GET" class="mt-4 mb-4 col-lg-6">
                <input class=" mb-3 form-control" type="disabled" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre?>" readonly >
                <input class="mb-3 form-control" type="text" name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" value="<?php echo $apellidos?>" readonly>
                <input class="mb-3 form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" value="<?php echo $email?>" readonly>
                <input class="mb-3 form-control" type="phone" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" value="<?php echo $telefono?>" readonly>
                <!-- <input name="id" type="text" value="<?php      echo $show['id']; ?>"> -->
                <div class="col mt-3 text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Cambiar</button>
                </div>
                <!-- <p class="mt-5"><?php print_r($resultado) ?></p> -->
                
            </form>
             <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Básicamente son dos formularios en uno se puede escribir y en otro no, eso depende de si tiene datos ese usuario

Este sería el código php para leer los datos de la base de datos:

```
  $nombre = '';
  $apellidos = '';
  $email = '';
  $telefono = '';

 if ($pdo) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
while($arr = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $nombre = $arr['nombre'];
  $apellidos = $arr['apellidos'];
  $email = $arr['email'];
  $telefono = $arr['telefono'];
}
 } else {
   echo 'Hubo un problema de conexión';
 }
```

Después por último intente hacer una condición para que si  el usuario tiene datos se muestre el segundo formulario

```
           <h3>Cambiar información de contacto</h3>


<?php
if (!$_GET):
?>

        <form method="POST" class="mt-4 mb-4 col-lg-6">
            <input class=" mb-3 form-control" type="disabled" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre?>" >
            <input class="mb-3 form-control" type="text" name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" value="<?php echo $apellidos?>">
            <input class="mb-3 form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" value="<?php echo $email?>">
            <input class="mb-3 form-control" type="phone" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" value="<?php echo $telefono?>">
            <input name="id" type="text" value="<?php      echo $show['id']; ?>">
            <div class="col mt-3 text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Cambiar</button>
            </div>
            <!-- <p class="mt-5"><?php print_r($resultado) ?></p> -->
            
        </form>

        <?php
        endif
        ?>

        <!-- Si el usuario tiene datos -->
        <form method="GET" class="mt-4 mb-4 col-lg-6">
            <input class=" mb-3 form-control" type="disabled" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre?>" readonly >
            <input class="mb-3 form-control" type="text" name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" value="<?php echo $apellidos?>" readonly>
            <input class="mb-3 form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" value="<?php echo $email?>" readonly>
            <input class="mb-3 form-control" type="phone" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" value="<?php echo $telefono?>" readonly>
            <!-- <input name="id" type="text" value="<?php      echo $show['id']; ?>"> -->
            <div class="col mt-3 text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Cambiar</button>
            </div>
            <!-- <p class="mt-5"><?php print_r($resultado) ?></p> -->
            
        </form>
        <!-- Si el usuario tiene datos -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Resumiendo, quiero cambiar el formulario si el usuario tiene datos de contacto por ejemplo lo he intentado con la condición if(_GET) pero no lo consigo si me pueden ayudar lo agradezco

Comment: Hola jonas, estas usando el metodo `GET` de forma erroneo, dejame explicarte que onda, cuando utilizas `GET` en un formulario es porque los vas a mandar a una URI en tu `action`, es decir si tu `action="search.php"` y utilizas `method="GET"`, vas a obtener una redireccion a una pagina con el siguiente url `search.php?nombre=value&apellido=value....etc.`, el metodo `POST` funciona para trabajar con los valores dentro del cuerpo del script aqui te dejo una pequeña guia [Diferencia GET y POST](https://pc-solucion.es/2018/06/06/diferencias-entre-el-metodo-get-y-post/) saludos

Comment: Si gustas entrar a la sala de [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128908/ayuda) para solucionar problemas juntos eres bienvenido

Answer (score 0):

En la parte de los comentarios te deje una explicacion de algunos errores que estas cometiendo al momento de interpretar los metodos, pero aqui te dejo un script que puede ayudarte.

Al momento de hacer la solicitud en la base de datos no estas especificando que usuario es, entonces la consulta que tienes actualmente te regresa la lista completa de todos los usuarios. Te dare un ejemplo de como se pudiera hacer, ya tu lo adaptas a tus necesidades.

```
  $id= 45; //el usuario tiene la id 45 como ejemplo
  $nombre = '';
  $apellidos = '';
  $email = '';
  $telefono = '';

 if ($pdo) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = ?";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt = $pdo->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
  $arr = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $nombre = $arr['nombre'];
  $apellidos = $arr['apellidos'];
  $email = $arr['email'];
  $telefono = $arr['telefono'];
 } else {
   echo 'Hubo un problema de conexión';
 }
```

y por parte del formulario estaria el siguiente codigo, **OJO** en este ejemplo asumo que `script.php` es donde estas ejectuando el formulario, tu lo cambias por el nombre a tu script local

```
    <form action="/script.php" method="POST" class="mt-4 mb-4 col-lg-6">
        <input class=" mb-3 form-control" type="text" disabled="disabled" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?=$nombre?>" >
        <input class="mb-3 form-control" type="text" name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" value="<?=$apellidos?>">
        <input class="mb-3 form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" value="<?=$email?>">
        <input class="mb-3 form-control" type="phone" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" value="<?php echo $telefono?>">
        <input name="id" type="text" value="<?=$show['id']?>">
        <div class="col mt-3 text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Cambiar</button>
        </div>
        
    </form>
```

no es necesario crear una condicionante para saber si existe un valor en las variables, ya que al principio la estamos definiendo como vacia, por lo tanto si no existe registro de informacion en la base de datos nos regresara un valor vacio, en caso que exista nos regresara el dato registrado.